# Is there a way I can list out conditionally from a value from a Json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, button, axios

I'm trying to create a new button that lists out all the movies that Sean Connery played in, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
**Prettier 2.7.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAgCU4BDMGAGn2HwFcBnOAZRhPnwF98AzHCdfAB0QOUuWEBuQVAzY8+ejACeAGzgATHnwHDFqjQFpIWaAhj1J02bgIkAHqgj0t-ISHuOLIKVGmQoivgAQrQwMND4ALwKymrqAHQARqHhUAAG0vj4iWQA1gDmfLRQ6kYQKrhI2Sp5PlmQFThVAO4AFqjwdTzQMAb0qABecFUATAAMmHZdmCTq6qhQ+VUAjBN2+ABsa12JuOpwOAY4s6gMVQCsk13oJDj5Cytr+NuZ+GC0OPSV+NgL8Dg+NI+aTcYrkRxQYIpaAAYRUqDAuQAFABKaivfyBADaDAO9CojBgAFVGJ8ALpROiMFhsOCorqYgjcOAwMCtAAibBIlKRykwcDRkQAfOjIVl8B4nK9xfh4vkWUjpTK3K0wph6EgAPSawZQbgAR3oAE4RlAAMzxOB2ODveAGEiYVDxBgGZpwRQGZbxEg3AbQEjNejxYya-YAN01DtQmrDI016AgYdQ7uESqyKLTspgrQQSKRono2ACAqiIuAmfq0ECN0w-PUAEEcMclDyC0XGPF1FyM2LleL4jW8x04OhBSLh+gsXy4BSAD6z-C8pT8qKRaLCeaici4Lz4ABke-wE87qC34RwaPni+nq-XIBgHTUAH0vothPvD8eHzBn6-8peFyXFc1zvBMkzgJ8lFIHB3wPI94HQAdE2TSDoJRHs+xleJuFQFR-jzYpUH1Wg4AANRIFQxzoGRiLIiiUS6PtCRJPEkRoKdlxnKpG2bbDtCRLF4iEqA4GafAmAVGs6x4kglBRMkUQ4BjMyUhkqyZFk2QkkgoBhaARJwFtoiRKAfRLYVy18MUOFeDhgTFUQYA+SFFV7fAAB55jDIVM081BvIrDzWhGIUgmgTROVYHJGHczVgp8tyZXc1pzgSzDxThBFcnwCJszgbJoQCfBwgUOB8ry-B4UCCBuAlFQVGKnNsnC-AwOTAByCxEuVTcbXPfFmpKCVt0+KhRDUEhGHwKDbioHTNG-NQFGgfIuvS2KUoSwL3JCMIIlheFEUiYBUVLHhNI5LlFRAXYSifMhz2ERTQpa+sRvoWLdtSNLMOAXFPg-RdAqydzaBUH70qyP7SXoAB+JJwvukb4cHJF-qoBZ9jsKjXMh5V3PhfBcjgJRjsxq0OCFdzuVaURuEiYRVRgdUtR1AY9UNE1zUta1bTge1HWdehXXdXovR9Eg-VMwNg34UM4AjKMYzjNqUxAIVoYODhYpIKnNXhCHIfQmzuqSzUwcNmVFN80N-MtjyvPtkGvv23TDtyY7TuFc7WUu1hrt696nsp9lTz6ndPsKp3qH+5w4NxyHQfB4HxU1z54cD-qUYdPNM9wHGU6SwnidJ4A85wSmy7Dkbtf11Bo6t63TfFWKLcCpu+1ix3fO75udsKnK3ayz2qOZX3IpIa7Fogv9g6FJgVo+zUXagaO07jw8E-Wtvm5ldf4enl8VuzzA80Pv8C93-Hi5J47z5Wyv78WWuDcL-BjZT1vk+bjv8dtgLup+QAetFeg9MpHROqPC6E9rqq1QrcOeABZZC+UACa0FI57VXoFdegMt6YSTg3VOscUYoPgTgE+eY4EzQvGdfBeMCaoCJrfYA1DoKVzYbcF+9c34fyvl-aOv8za907iIghK956kEhHpKABklCdXwAAGVQNVWqyDwJLwkTbMRIN-4-WUlAE20grRyAIPsbgJAwYEBXuA3IEgQAUBABATAD4qzIFALcPgzQAAKtwED0GQO4FQzRZIBMcYkY4iIWRMDMsokSyALEqEYOEyJxMYBMBmGABY+RkAwBwCRRxI5EgaH2OoRROl8i0BIPKAAYrgG4YRsmBMseEBxIBVToBUAAdXaPAQsZBmD+I6P5DoShAlgHoGEtAxY8DeOOPkG4CSKLJJAAAK3oHYJg2S1AAEVaAQHgEspJcBHEzE+AcQJORikqDaZgHAfwumoHUNmZAAAOMYpy+CMC6ccTAgS7nugOGGOAbTiIHLgHM5xASUCTQMCJDQGg2miGImHOZ1TFlIESSsxg6BUC5PySckA-RFi7P2YczFyzCVRUec81oyARiOLySQXC2S9LoAxSAd05w2m4gACokESNCrFhKwwkQAJIlDMEwMA9yXH1hKCwfQRzGAcA4EAA)

```bash
--parser babel
```

**Input:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const mappedArray = (response.data)
          .map((item) => item[type] || (type === "directors" && item.director) || (type === "title_song" && item.title_song) || (type === "movie_year" && item.movie_year))
          .filter((uniqueVal) => uniqueVal);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedArray)])});
      });
  const fetchSeanConnery = (name) =>{

  }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}><a href="https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies">{user}</a></li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button>Sean Connery's List of Movies</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

I saw a way to use Json.parse, but it didn't work when I tried it, so I would appreciate it if I could get some assistance on this. Thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const mappedArray = response.data
          .map(
            (item) =>
              item[type] ||
              (type === "directors" && item.director) ||
              (type === "title_song" && item.title_song) ||
              (type === "movie_year" && item.movie_year)
          )
          .filter((uniqueVal) => uniqueVal);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedArray)]) });
      });
  };

  const fetchActorsMovies = (name) => {
      axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      ).then(response => {
        setMovies(response.data.filter(item => item.bond_actor === name).map(item => item.movie_title));
      })
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href="https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies">
                  {user}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchActorsMovies("Sean Connery")}>Sean Connery's List of Movies</Button>
        {movies && (
          <ul>
            {movies?.map((movie) => (
              <li key={movie}>{movie}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```